# Defining field label in a block - on error, field_with_errors div tag not in right place

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, label

I am using `validates_acceptance_of :terms, :message => "must be accepted"` in my `user.rb` model, and am using `bootstrap-sass`.

My check box code looks like this in the view:

```
<div class="control-group">
  <%= f.label :terms, :class => "control-label" do %>
    Accept <%= link_to('Terms of Use *', "#myTOUModal", :"data-toggle" => "modal") %>
  <% end %>
  <div class="controls">
    <%= f.check_box :terms %>
  </div>
</div>
```

For some reason, when the terms check box isn't selected on form submission, the appropriate error message shows up at the top of the form, but there is a problem with the `field_with_errors` div class wrapping around the check box label.

The HTML for the rendered page looks like this:

```
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="user_terms">
    Accept <a href="#myTOUModal" data-toggle="modal">Terms of Use *</a>
  </label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input name="user[terms]" type="hidden" value="0" />
    <div class="field_with_errors">
      <input id="user_terms" name="user[terms]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The result is that the check box field label isn't highlighted on error. Is there a way to force the div tag placement for the `field_with_errors` class to show up just after the `<div class="control-group">` tag? Why does using a block to define a field label throw off the `field_with_errors` tag placement? Does anyone have experience with this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug i think. The problem is in block. Define your label without block and everything works.

Try something like:

```
<% modal_html = capture do >
  Accept <%= link_to('Terms of Use *', "#myTOUModal", :"data-toggle" => "modal") %>
<% end %>

<%= f.label :terms, modal_html, :class => "control-label" %>
```

Or helper:

```
def modal_html
  #Q{Accept #{link_to('Terms of Use *', "#myTOUModal", :"data-toggle" => "modal")} }.html_safe
end
```

Comment: Ok. I did this as a block because I couldn't get the modal reference to work in one line. Any ideas on how to pull this off?

Comment: Try this, if not, use helper.